# How do I revert a branch to a commit and put the forward commits to a new branch?

Tags: git, github, revert

I have a git look like this, for both remote and local.

```
A---B---C---D master
```

Now I want my `master` to be reverted at `B` commit, but I also don't want to lose my `C` and `D` commit.

Is there a way to make my git look like this for both remote and local?

```
      C---D new branch
     /
A---B master
```

---

I know it's not possible to backtrack to a previous point, maybe something like this also does the trick:

```
                          C---D new branch
                         /
A---B---C---D---revertToB master
```

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Note down the commit SHAs of `C` and `D`. While on `master`, `git reset --hard HEAD~2`. Then `git checkout -b new-branch`, and `git cherry-pick` the aforementioned commits. Your local `master` will need to be force pushed to the remote, but the end state will be as you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* get this:

> ```
>      C--D   <-- new-branch
>     /
> A--B   <-- master
> ```

but to do that, you must force *all* Git repositories that have a branch named `master` pointing to existing commit `D` to retract their `master` to point to existing commit `B`.  That can be difficult, since Git "likes" to *add* commits, but not to "remove" them.

To get this locally, assuming you have:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

run:

```
git branch new-branch master
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

You now have:

```
     C--D   <-- new-branch
    /
A--B   <-- master (HEAD)
```

locally.  Unfortunately, the other Git repository over at `origin` still has *its* `master` pointing to commit `D`.  Any clones made from that other Git repository also have *their* `master` pointing to commit `D`.  You must get all of those repositories to do the same kind of retraction.  If there is only the one repository, *and* you have permission to use `git push --force` to retract it, you can now:

```
git push origin new-branch   # to create new-branch on origin
git push -f origin master    # to force them to retract their master
```

(You may want to add `-u` to the first `git push`.)

---

To get the safer thing you're looking for—adding a new commit to `master` that resets it back to the way it was at commit `B`—you can use:

```
git branch temp master
```

which sets things up to read:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD), temp
```

Then you can run `git revert -n HEAD~2..HEAD; git commit`, or `git read-tree -u HEAD~2; git commit` to make a new commit `E` whose snapshot matches that of `B`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- temp
          \
           E   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Existing commits `C-D` are stuck where they are.  If you want `new-branch` to be a descendant of `master`, you must now create it.  Note that, if you are OK with `new-branch` pointing to existing commit `D`, you can just use the name `new-branch` instead of `temp` and you will have what you wanted.  But if you need a new commit—let's call it `F`—that comes after `E` that matches the contents of commit `D`, you can create new-branch now:

```
git checkout -b new-branch master
```

giving:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- temp
          \
           E   <-- master, new-branch (HEAD)
```

Now you can:

- revert the reversion commit `E`, or
- `git read-tree` commit `D` and commit, or
- `git cherry-pick` commits `C` and `D`.

To do the first, run `git revert master` or `git revert HEAD` (either suffices) and you have:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- temp
          \
           E   <-- master
            \
             F   <-- new-branch (HEAD)
```

To do the second, run `git read-tree -u temp; git commit` to make new commit `F` (you will need to enter a new commit message).

To do the third, run `git cherry-pick temp~2..temp`; this will produce:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- temp
          \
           E   <-- master
            \
             C'-D'  <-- new-branch (HEAD)
```

where the names `C'` and `D'` indicate that these are cherry-picked copies of `C` and `D` respectively.  (When we reverted to make `E` we combined both undoing steps, using `git revert -n`, so `E` is not exactly an undo of either `D` *or* `C`, but rather an undo of both at once.)

It's now safe to remove the name `temp` as we do not need it to find `C` and `D` conveniently any more.  (We did not need it all along, as we could have found them anyway, but it was convenient to have a name for commit `D` so that commits `C` and `B` were `temp~2` and `temp~1` respectively.)

It's now safe (and does not require a `git push --force`) to `git push origin master new-branch`.

---

Alternatively, you could, instead of creating `temp`, make the name `new-branch` point to commit `D` all along.  That is, starting with:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

you could do:

```
git branch new-branch master
```

giving:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD), new-branch
```

Then you can "undo" the `C-D` commits on `master` as before, e.g., producing:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- new-branch
          \
           E   <-- master (HEAD)
```

As the next step, you could run:

```
git checkout new-branch; git merge -s ours master
```

to make Git create a new *merge* commit `F` whose snapshot matches that of existing commit `D`:

```
A--B--C--D---F   <-- new-branch
          \ /
           E   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Commit `F` is now *ahead of* `master` as before, but when reading backwards in a straight line, across first-parent links, it never visits commit `E`: Git walks back from `F` to `D` to `C` and so on.  Again, this is **provided** you use `--first-parent` when having `git log` or `git rev-list` traverse back from `F`.  By default, a traversal back from `F` visits *both* commits `E` *and* `D` (and since the default is to go by committer-date order, you'll see `E`, which we made later than `D`, before seeing `D`).

Comment: Wow, that's a very thorough explanation, thank you very much! Also, is there a way to `cherry-pick` a series of commits? Like it's not just `C` or `D`, it's from `C` to `Z`, do I have to manually pick them one by one?

Comment: Yes: `git cherry-pick` takes range arguments, as shown above with `temp~2..temp` for instance. Note that a range includes the final commit (`temp`) but excludes the first one (`temp~2`) so if you want to include commit `C` make sure your "stop" commit on the left is `B`, not `C`.